# OST Name used in Episode 18 Gundam Build Fighter Try

Tags: music, gundam-build-fighters-try

In episode 18 of *Gundam Build Fighter Try*, the music starts from 12:44 (maybe? I'm not sure, correct me if I'm wrong) to 14:46.

I've been searching the whole YouTube, internet, and SoundCloud but won't get an easy hand on it.

Somehow, Sunrise like to use the old OST from *GBF* to *GBFT*, so I assume it's an old OST from *GBF* instead of *GBFT* (cause I have a full set of *GBFT* OST)

Here is the [link to the episode](https://youtu.be/tcyas4ux6ho?t=12m43s) on the official Gundam channel.

Answer (score 0):

The song name is "Gundaba Colosseum". It's [the 14th track of *Gundam Build Fighters Try Original Soundtrack 02*](https://otakumode.com/shop/54f9200d66c24cac49d2a675/Gundam-Build-Fighters-Try-Original-Soundtrack-02).